# Neutral to bearish options strategy above stock price

Tags: options

If a stock is trading at $30 and I believe it will go no higher than $33, is there a spread that I can create above $33? This is a neutral to bearish strategy.

I've looked at a debt put spread:

```
sell $34 put
buy $37 put
```

They always end up with a negative profit potential or very small profit. Is there some spread that can work in this scenario? If not a spread, what is the better option strategy?

Comment: It's not clear what your objective is.  If you are trying to capitalize on a rise to $33 then your proposed spread is inappropriate.  The spread has other problems but I'm not going to make guesses without clarification.  Why did you choose these strikes?

Comment: The strikes were chosen in an effort to maximize gain.

Comment: @4thSpace , can you clarify.  Do you think the stock is going **higher**?  (I don't understand what you mean by "neutral to bearish".)

Comment: @4thSpace - Why do you think that combination of strikes maximizes gain?

Comment: @Fattie - The information provided is insufficient to make realistic suggestions.  At best, this spread could be a volatility play if a large IV contraction was anticipated but it's still chasing peanuts.

Answer (score 3):

Because your proposed spread is deep ITM, you are paying almost the intrinsic value of the spread because there's only a small amount of time premium.  That means that you have a low delta, low expected profit position with a  very asymmetric R/R with  a high probability of capturing a small potential gain and a small probability of losing the large debit cost.  So if the time premium involved was 30 cents, with a 3 point difference in strikes, ignoring slippage and commissions, you'd  have to get this right 9 times out of 10 to break even.  Not good odds.

Your spread might be acceptable if implied volatility was high (undisclosed by you), you were outright bearish and you were looking to capture a short term IV contraction.  The higher the IV, the higher the small amount of time premium involved in this spread and the modestly lower your debit cost will be.

If you had a downside share price limit as well, say $27 which means that you expect a range of $3 on either side of the current price of $30 then a short Iron Condor might be appropriate since it benefits from time decay on both sides.  In addition, if price moves against you, you might be able to roll the unaffected side in, bringing in some additional premium to slow the loss on the affected side.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, being short volatility tends to produce a large chance of small gains and a small chance of large losses. You wish to profit by selling insurance on a relatively unlikely event (the stock rising more than 10%), but evidently people will not pay very much for this insurance.

A theoretically equivalent but more efficient version of your suggestion is a bear *credit* spread, short the $34 *call* and long the $37 *call*. The bid-ask will be narrower for these out-of-the-money options versus the in-the-money ones for the debit spread. This may slightly improve your profit potential. But ultimately to have more profit you would need to take more risk.

You said you want to bet that the stock will not go above $33. If, however, you specifically think the stock will *rise* but not that much, you could consider a plain covered call. This would have greater profit potential but would leave you more exposed to a potential decline in the stock.

Comment: "Indeed, being short volatility tends to produce a large chance of small gains and a small chance of large losses." thatt's pretty astute !

Comment: He said he's neutral to bearish but he doesn't see the stock rising above $33.  The covered call is suitable for rising to $33 but not suitable for the undefined bearish outlook.

Answer (score 0):

For neutral to bearish strategy, I would consider these ones (assuming the scenario, the price will stay the same or we believe it can go down):

Let's take the options for a stock with the value about $30 in a real life example. I chose Dropbox. Have the expiration of about 2 months.

It's 22nd September, so I pulled those ones with the expiration of 3rd Friday in November.

**Long Put Spread**

Here we use puts and strikes you stated above:

- **BUY 11/19 PUT @ 37** e.g. for 7.00
- **SELL 11/19 PUT @ 34** e.g. for 4.15
- ***Max net profit 0.15** (Debited amount: 2.85, max loss 2.85, max output 3.00)*
- ***Reward to risk ratio: 1 : 19** (0.15 : 2.85)*

[image]

**Short Call Spread**

E.g. call prices are better (higher) than prices for puts:

- **BUY 11/19 CALL @ 37** e.g. for 0.21
- **SELL 11/19 CALL @ 34** e.g. for 0.45
- ***Max net profit 0.24** (Credited amount: 0.24, max loss 3.00)*
- ***Reward to risk ratio: 1 : 12.5** (0.24 : 3.00)*

[image]

**Call Diagonal spread**

This is not neutral to bearish, but I just mention this interesting one, if you expect the price to stay below 33 before Nov 19, but also expect the volatility or stock price to go higher before the end of the year (it is a long calendar spread but with different strikes):

- **BUY 22/1/21 CALL @ 37** e.g. for 0.43 (front option)
- **SELL 21/11/19 CALL @ 33** e.g. for 0.45 (back option)

It's not possible to calculate exactly the profit/loss, as we don't know the price of the back one at the moment when the front one expires.

- ***Max net profit: not limited** (Credited amount: 0.02, max loss: less than 4.00)* (it is less, because the back option will still have some remaining premium for two months)
- ***Reward to risk ratio: ? : 12.5** (? : 4.00)*

[image]

So it's like we got the January option for free, as the front option with November expiration helped us to pay its cost. If we expect the stock to rise before the year end, the profit is not capped from the upside in this strategy.
The reason why it's less than 4.00: In the worst scenario, the stock would end up with e.g. 36.99 in price, you would have you pay the difference of 3.99 and you could sell the back option for remaining premium.

It is hard to time it, but it brings better potential, especially if we stay at your original assumptions, that the stock will not go higher till certain date.

Comment: While your 3rd example is a calendar, technically it's a diagonal.  It has multiple issues.  T=It has a terrible B/A spread width. The Jan '22 call is the back month not the front.  You can calculate the exact profit/loss for any price if you make an implied volatility assumption.  You have indicated the maximum loss to be $3 and $4. Pick one. If the stock rises dramatically (low 40's), the Jan '22 $37 call will trade for its intrinsic value and the diagonal will approach its maximum loss (little to no time premium remaining). This only works well if DBX stays below $34 before Nov expiration

Comment: Hi @BobBaerker, first, it's in the title of a paragraph, that it is a Diagonal. Second, the spread you complain is OK, what you see is merged Front's bid with Back's Ask, so that's why it look as a terrible spread. Thank you for your attention and found mistyped value. I've fixed it.

Comment: Your answer still need fixing - lots of errors.  A $34/$37 diagonal call  has a maximum risk of $3.00 if all options go to parity (less the cost of the spread).   Your answer still says $4.00. Since your spread generated a credit of two cents, max risk is $2.98. If the stock goes to $36.99, you would have to pay the difference of $2.99  on the spread not $3.99 . This diagonal call spread is most definitely neutral to bearish and the hope for  volatility expansion is for before near month expiration (November) not the end of the year).